# RootScope not working when used in a third controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, rootscope

I am using rootScope variable in 3 controllers. The first controller sets the value, which is used by the second controller for ng-show. But when I tried to control the ng-show from the third controller via same rootScope variable, its not working. **"modstat"**  is the variable. I am new to Angular. So someone please help me with this. The code is given below:

```js
urlboxControllers.controller('MenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'SessionService', 'AuthenticationService', 'ModalService',
 function($scope, $location, $rootScope, SessionService, AuthenticationService, ModalService){
  $scope.fname = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.fname);
  $scope.lname = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.lname);
  $scope.addLink = function() {
   $rootScope.modstat = !$rootScope.modstat;
   $rootScope.modserv = true;
   //ModalService.set(1); 
  }; 
  
  
  
  $scope.logout = function() { 
  AuthenticationService.logout().success(function() {
   $location.path('/login');
  }); 
   
  };

 }]);
 
urlboxControllers.controller('ModalCtrl', ['$scope',  '$rootScope', '$location', 'SessionService', 'ModalService',
function($scope, $location, $rootScope, SessionService, ModalService){
  $scope.grid = {};

  
  $scope.grid.uid = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.id);
  $scope.modserv = function() {
          return $rootScope.modserv;
      };
   
  if($scope.modserv){
   $scope.mtitle= "Create a Link";
  }
  else if(!$scope.modserv){
   $scope.mtitle= "Update Link";
  }
  
  $scope.statcheck = function() {
   console.log("stat" + $rootScope.modstat);
          return $rootScope.modstat;
      };

  
  
  $scope.icons = [{ico: 'cloud'}, {ico: 'envelope'}, {ico: 'pencil'}, {ico: 'search'}, {ico: 'heart'}, {ico: 'star'},
   {ico: 'user'}, {ico: 'home'}, {ico: 'cog'}, {ico: 'file'}, {ico: 'time'}, {ico: 'download-alt'}, {ico: 'download'},
  {ico: 'upload'}, {ico: 'lock'}, {ico: 'play-circle'}, {ico: 'tag'}, {ico: 'tags'}, {ico: 'book'}, {ico: 'bookmark'}, 
  {ico: 'print'}, {ico: 'map-marker'}, {ico: 'tint'}, {ico: 'edit'}, {ico: 'share'}, {ico: 'plus-sign'},
   {ico: 'minus-sign'}, {ico: 'ok-sign'}, {ico: 'info-sign'}, {ico: 'leaf'}, {ico: 'fire'}, {ico: 'calendar'},
   {ico: 'comment'}, {ico: 'folder-close'}, {ico: 'hdd'}, {ico: 'bullhorn'}, {ico: 'bell'}, {ico: 'certificate'},
   {ico: 'wrench'}, {ico: 'globe'}, {ico: 'tasks'}, {ico: 'filter'}, {ico: 'briefcase'}, {ico: 'link'},
   {ico: 'paperclip'}, {ico: 'pushpin'}, {ico: 'log-in'}, {ico: 'flash'}, {ico: 'log-out'}, {ico: 'save'}, {ico: 'open'},
  {ico: 'saved'}, {ico: 'send'}, {ico: 'floppy-disk'}, {ico: 'floppy-saved'}, {ico: 'tower'}, {ico: 'stats'}, 
  {ico: 'cloud-download'}, {ico: 'cloud-upload'}, {ico: 'tree-conifer'}, {ico: 'tree-deciduous'} ];
  
  
  
  $scope.create = function(){
   if($scope.modserv) {
    
     $scope.repo = ModalService.mvalidate($scope.grid);
     
     if($scope.repo.stat === 'error'){
      $scope.errcol = $scope.repo; 
     }
     else if($scope.repo.stat === 'success'){
      $scope.errcol = $scope.repo; 
      ModalService.create($scope.grid).success(function(data) {
      
       if(data='Saved')
       {
        $scope.grid = {};
        $scope.succ = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Saved</div>';
        $rootScope.modstat = false;
       }
       else {
        alert(data.error);
       }
      
      });
     }
  
   
   }

  };
  

 
  
  
  
 }]);
 
 
 urlboxControllers.controller('GridCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'SessionService', 'GridService', '$rootScope',
function($scope, $location, SessionService, GridService, $rootScope){
  $scope.uid = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.id);
  
  GridService.gdata($scope.uid).success(function(data) {
    $scope.grids=data;
   });
  
  $('#gridmod').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
     GridService.gdata($scope.uid).success(function(data) {
    $scope.grids=data;  
   });
   
  });
  
  $scope.getLocation = function() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition($scope.showPosition);
      } else {
          console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
      }
  };
 $scope.showPosition = function (position) {
     $scope.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        $scope.lng = position.coords.longitude;
  GridService.weather($scope.lat, $scope.lng).success(function(data) {
    $scope.wdata = data;
    $scope.weather = $scope.wdata.weather;
    $scope.main = $scope.wdata.main;
    $scope.conv = 273.15;
    $scope.temp = $scope.main.temp - $scope.conv;
    $scope.code = $scope.weather[0].icon.slice(0,-1);
   });
 };
  $scope.getLocation();
  
  $scope.upLink = function(lid) {
   //$rootScope.modstat = !$rootScope.modstat;
   console.log("test" + $rootScope.modstat);
   $rootScope.modserv = true;
  };
  $scope.delLink = function(lid) {
   console.log(lid);
  };
 
 
 }]);
```

Comment: Without being an expert in Angular, shouldn't the function variables be in the same order as the array stating what objects to inject?

Comment: @Andreas Thank you very much. Its fixed. Please post your comment as your answer.

Comment: Great! Added the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting the objects to inject in the function they need to come in the same order as you state in the array. Your example ->

```
urlboxControllers.controller('MenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'SessionService', 'AuthenticationService', 'ModalService',
function($scope, $location, $rootScope, SessionService, AuthenticationService, ModalService){}
```

should be

```
urlboxControllers.controller('MenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'SessionService', 'AuthenticationService', 'ModalService',
function($scope, $rootScope, $location, SessionService, AuthenticationService, ModalService){}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is related to the second controller.

The second's controller declaration has the `$location` and `$rootScope` arguments inverted in the function's sign. You are using this:

```
urlboxControllers.controller('ModalCtrl', ['$scope',  '$rootScope', '$location', 'SessionService', 'ModalService',
function($scope, $location, $rootScope, SessionService, ModalService){
```

instead of:

```
urlboxControllers.controller('ModalCtrl', ['$scope',  '$rootScope', '$location', 'SessionService', 'ModalService',
function($scope,  $rootScope, $location, SessionService, ModalService){
```

In the second controller you are setting an attribute into the `$location` object (that's why you don't get any error) and then it's retrieved through the `$rootScope`

Comment: No  it didn't work. The modal is call correctly from the "Menu Ctrl" but not from the Gridctrl